# How to extend partitions in CentOS Linux

Tags: linux, centos, partition, lvm, storage

I want to extend the /opt partition with 50 GB.

I have CentOS 7 on VMWare esxi with 50 GB of storage. T**he server is partitioned during the installation process as follows:**

[image: partitions]

**And here is the output of df -h, lsbk, and fdisk -l:**

[image: df -h]
[image: lsblk & fdisk -l]

---

**After that I have turned off the machine and added 50 GB to the disk from VMWare portal :**

[image]

**Here is the output of df -h, lsblk, and fdisk -l after resizing the disk (adding 50 GB):**

[image: df -h & lsblk]

[image: fdisk -l]

[image: vgs]

[image: vgdisplay]

**I want to allocate the newly added 50 GB to /opt. I have tried different methods but non of them worked.**

Comment: first add the newly added 50GB to your LVM, using pvresize /dev/sda3 (Adding the free space to the LVM), then use lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/vg_centos-opt (it will first resize the VG then the LV) and then as you are in ext4 resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_centos-opt

Comment: @admstg, it is not required to allocate all the space. To be modest in this case is desirable and wise. Also if you add `-r` to `lvextend` you will have your filesystem extended automatically

Comment: The comments are correct but please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).